# Freshly installed wiki still shows red links for pages that have been created?

Tags: mediawiki, sql-server-2012

I just set up MediaWiki for a test run on my laptop. Windows 7, PHP 5.4, SQL Server 2012 SP2, IIS 7, MediaWiki 1.23.6. The installation went smoothly [once I got everything in order](https://serverfault.com/questions/643956/configuring-php-and-wikimedia-to-use-microsoft-sql-server) and I can create and edit pages.

On the Main page, I edited in a link to a Projects page.

```
[[Projects]] page
```

The Projects link was red, as it should be, and I clicked it, made the page, and saved it. However, when I go back to the Main page, the Projects link is still red and the tooltip says "this page doesn't exist". Clicking on the link will take me to the page I created successfully.

How can I fix existing pages showing up as red links when they should show up as blue/purple?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to [configure the job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue#Set_up). Link colour is not updated immediately across all of your wiki, to save resources.

Add something like this to your crontab -e:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/wiki/maintenance/runJobs.php > /var/log/runJobs.log 2>&1
```

(see manual for more).